# SQL Period Over Period Calculation

Tags: t-sql

I have a T-SQL query that summarizes for some partial time periods such as 2022-04-01 to 2022-04-15 where I want to do a comparative period over period comparison. This means for the 15 days above, how do they compare against the same 15 days of the previous month.

Here's an example of the query for the specified 15 days:

```
declare @StartDate date = '2022-04-01'
declare @EndDate date = '2022-04-15'
declare @PreviousStartDate date = '2022-03-01'
declare @PreviousEndDate date = '2022-03-15'

select *,
    CloseRate = cast(Sales as float) / nullif(Customers,0)
from (
    select
        count(*) as Customers,
        count(Responded) as Responded,
        count(Responded) / nullif(cast(count(*) as float),0) as ResponseRate,
        avg(TimeToRespond) as AvgResponseTime,
        count(distinct SaleId) as Sales
    from Customer c
        join Retailer r on c.RetailerId = r.Id
        left join CustomerSale cs on c.Id = cs.CustomerId
    where c.DateKey >= @StartDate
        and c.DateKey < @EndDate
) t
```

What are some good ways to retrieve the two timeframes and perform the period over period calculations incrementally against my query without literally executing the same query twice but with different date ranges specified and then left outer joining them?

Thanks!

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be useful.

Comment: How do you define "good ways"? Is it performance you seek? Is it clarity? Is it speed of development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use Start/End date parameters that are inclusive, thereby allowing the use of "Between" (if possible) just to simplify the query. Then add a "Period" column to your inner query and group by that as follows:

```
select
    case when c.DateKey between @StartDate and @EndDate then 'This'
         when c.DateKey between @PreviousStartDate and @PreviousEndDate then 'Prev'
         end as [Period],
    count(*) as Customers,
    count(Responded) as Responded,
    count(Responded) / nullif(cast(count(*) as float),0) as ResponseRate,
    avg(TimeToRespond) as AvgResponseTime,
    count(distinct SaleId) as Sales
from Customer c
    join Retailer r on c.RetailerId = r.Id
    left join CustomerSale cs on c.Id = cs.CustomerId
where   c.DateKey between @StartDate and @EndDate
or      c.DateKey between @PreviousStartDate and @PreviousEndDate
group by case when c.DateKey between @StartDate and @EndDate then 'This'
              when c.DateKey between @PreviousStartDate and @PreviousEndDate then 'Prev'
              end
```